# Why Iron-Router in Telescope is not recognizing the _id parameter that is passed?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router, telescope

I am trying to make in response to an event, the Telescope go to post next/previous.

```
var y = Router.current().data().postedAt;
var nex = Posts.find({postedAt:{$gt:y}}, {sort: {postedAt:1}, limit:1});
nex.forEach(function(nex){ vai = nex._id;});
Router.go('post_page', vai, {_id:vai});
```

The problem is when I try to pass the `nex._id` to the router. It appears this message on the console:

> Error: Missing required parameters on path "/ posts /: _ id". The
>   missing params are: ["_id"]. The params object passed in was:
>   "erhqpuXxXgk9EA4Gg".

The `_id` is passed properly, but is not recognized. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your entire route code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work. See how was:

```
var y = Router.current().data().postedAt;
var nex = Posts.find({postedAt:{$gt:y}}, {sort: {postedAt: 1}, limit:1} );
nex.forEach(function(nex){ _id = nex._id;});
Router.go('post_page', {_id:this._id});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that your route is as below:

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', function () {
  this.render('Post');
}, {
  name: 'post_page'
});
```

Your Router.go method should be:

```
Router.go('post_page', {_id: vai});
```

Comment: Hello! I do not understand how this would help.